# C header não funciona

Tags: c

Estou tentando criar uma lista dinâmica, para tal criei um arquivo "list.c" para definir as funções de minha lista e um cabeçalho "list.h".

Com o cabeçalho "list.h" incluído dentro do "main.c" seria possível proceder com os meus estudos, porém ao compilar o "main.c" com a função "createList()", o compilador gera o seguinte erro:
"undefined reference to `createList'"

Utilizo o linux para programar, já tentei compilar manualmente através do terminal e através do visual studio code, porém o erro permanece.

Também já verifiquei se arquivos estão na mesma pasta, e se a syntax está correta, porém sem sucesso.

Preciso de uma solução, pois esse programa é para minha faculdade, estou estudando estrutura de dados e basicamente travei nesse problema.

Ainda não implementei a lista por conta desse problema, portanto a lista está parcialmente implementada.

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(){
    createList();
    return 0;
}
```

list.c

```
#include "list.h"

typedef struct node{
    int *data;
    struct node *nextNode;
} node;

typedef struct list{
    long long size;
    node *head;
} list;

void createList(){
    list list; 
}

void add(list *list, int *data){
    node node;
    node.data = data;
    list->head = &node;
    list->size++;
}
```

list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED

    typedef struct list list;
    typedef struct node node;
    void add(list *list, int *data);
    void createList();

#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você sabe, os arquivos `.h` são importados como **headers**, mas os arquivos `.c` são arquivos de código onde é aplicada a lógica do seu programa.

Para que você consiga usar as funções que estão em diferentes arquivos `.c`, você precisa unir os arquivos.

O método mais recomendado para fazer a união dos arquivos é compilando 1 por 1 e depois unindo eles.

```
$ gcc -c main.c -I.
$ gcc -c list.c -I.
$ gcc main.o list.o -I. -o lista.exe
```

Ou pode compilar todos de uma vez

```
$ gcc main.c list.c -I. -o lista.exe
```